# Can't get this scrollbar to work with Text widet in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I know there are a lot of questions on this but I need some help on getting this to work. Basically there is a Text widget and I want it to have a scroll bar on the right, vertical side of it. I want the scrollbar inside the Text widget and for it to always be visible. Here is my code so far. (BTW for some reason whenever I run stuff with .pack() the python console just freezes? So doing this with .grid() would be appreciated, if not possible thats ok):

```
console = Text(root, width=35, height=16)
console.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="w")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=console.yview)
console.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
```

Full code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket
import tkFont
#User Interface---------------------------------------
root = Tk()
root.title("MY GUI")
root.geometry("372x414+510+175")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
'''FONTS------------------------------------------------'''
label_f = tkFont.Font(family="Trebuchet MS", size="12" )
entry_f = tkFont.Font(family ="Courier", size = "12")
'''IP-----------------------------'''
target = Label(root, text="Target IP Adress:",font= label_f).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
userIP = StringVar()
tar_ent = Entry(root, width = "33", font=entry_f, textvariable = userIP)
tar_ent.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
'''Port ------------------------------'''
custom = Label(root, text = "Custom port scanner (Enter like 23,80,etc.)", font=label_f).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
userPort = StringVar()
cus_port = Entry(root, width="33", font=entry_f, textvariable=userPort)
cus_port.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w')
'''Results--------------------------'''
space = Label(root, text="")
space.grid(row=5, column=0)
console = Text(root, width=35, height=16)
console.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="w")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=console.yview)
console.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky='Ns')#side="right", fill="y")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix layout (`pack`, `grid`, `place`) for the same parent widget.

Replace the following line:

```
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
```

with:

```
scrollbar.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky='NS')
```

**UPDATE** according to the question change:

Here's the full code modified:

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket
import tkFont
#User Interface---------------------------------------
root = Tk()
root.title("MY GUI")
root.geometry("372x414+510+175")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
'''FONTS------------------------------------------------'''
label_f = tkFont.Font(family="Trebuchet MS", size="12" )
entry_f = tkFont.Font(family ="Courier", size = "12")
'''IP-----------------------------'''
target = Label(root, text="Target IP Adress:",font= label_f).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
userIP = StringVar()
tar_ent = Entry(root, width = "33", font=entry_f, textvariable = userIP)
tar_ent.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='WE', columnspan=2)
'''Port ------------------------------'''
custom = Label(root, text = "Custom port scanner (Enter like 23,80,etc.)", font=label_f).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
userPort = StringVar()
cus_port = Entry(root, width="33", font=entry_f, textvariable=userPort)
cus_port.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='WE', columnspan=2)
'''Results--------------------------'''
space = Label(root, text="")
space.grid(row=5, column=0)
console = Text(root, width=35, height=16)
console.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="WE")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=console.yview)
console.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky='Ns')

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm this worked except for the placement of the scrollbar. The scroll bar is like randomly floating to the right of the Text widget not really inside it? Any way to fix this?

Comment: @user3678184, I don't understand what you mean. It works for me. See this: http://i.imgur.com/wESqIlI.png

Comment: @user3678184, Could you post another question with a reproducible code?

Comment: Check my answer, I edited it so you can reproduce it

Comment: @user3678184, Replace `console.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="w")` with `console.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="WE")`. (to make the text widget stretch)

Comment: Haha I wanted the scrollbar to move to the left, not have the console move to the right because other widgets are gonna go on the right. Is this possible?

Comment: @user3678184, Change other widgets' grid options, too: `columnspan=2, sticky='WE'`. (result: http://i.imgur.com/nM04X1D.png)

Comment: is there any way we coulda kept the Text widgets heigh and width and just move the scroll bar into it?

Comment: @user3678184, Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Hmmm dang /: well thanks for all the help though man really appreciate it!

Comment: @user3678184, How about define your own widget that subclass Tkinter.Frame and include text/scrollbar widget?

Comment: Hmmm how might I go about doing that?